# Type that only allows values from an enum but does not require every value in the enum to be present

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
enum Foo {
  a,
  b,
  c
}

type Bar = {
  [key in keyof typeof Foo]: string;
}

const test: Bar = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};
```

The code complains that the `test` variable does not have the `c` property.

How can I alter the `Bar` type so that the keys from the enum are optional?

Comment: Make the properties optional as in `[key in keyof typeof Foo]?: string;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt):

```
enum Foo {
  a,
  b,
  c
}

type Bar = Partial<{
  [key in keyof typeof Foo]: string;
}>

const test: Bar = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments by @jcalz, mark the properties as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties):

```
enum Foo {
  a,
  b,
  c
}

type Bar = {
  [key in keyof typeof Foo]?: string;
}

const test: Bar = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution by utility types [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) and [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

```
type Bar = Partial<Record<keyof typeof Foo, string>>
```